# Beautifulsoupがimportできません。

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

`conda install beautifulsoup4` を実行した後、`from bs4 import Beautifulsoup` を実行しようとしたところ、

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Beautifulsoup' from 'bs4' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py)
```

となり、インポートすることができません。
`pip list` では beautifulsoup4 が確認できています。

どなたか解決策をご教授ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `Beautifulsoup` ではなく `BeautifulSoup` です。。。

Answer (score 0):

インストール時に指定するパッケージ名はすべて小文字の `beautifulsoup4` ですが、実際にモジュールとして import する際の名前は **B**eautiful**S**oup のように大文字混じりになります。

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: できました。初歩の初歩のとこですね。。

Comment: ありがとうございます！