# Pythonモジュールのbs4をimport出来ません

Tags: python, python3

コマンドプロンプトで、

```
C:>pip install bs4
```

と実行してPythonで

```
import bs4
```

としても、`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`
と言われ、実行できません。一応pipの時に、`Successfully installed bs4-0.0.1`と出力が返ってきたので、インストールはできていると思います。

python 3.10.4、OSはwindows 11で、VSCで実行してます。

これまでに試したこと:

- `pip show beautifulsoup4`でインストールしてあることを確認
- `pip install beautifulsoup4`を実行
- `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`に変えてみる(大文字にするのはBとSであっていますか？)
- Pythonの再インストール
- VSCodeの再インストール
- コマンドプロンプトからファイルを実行
- beautifulsoup4を使えている友達から、`beautifulsoup4-4.11.1.dist-info`、`bs4`、`bs4-0.0.1-py3.10.egg-info`というフォルダを貰って、
  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
  の既存のファイルと入れ替えてpip installする
- Powershellでpipを実行する
- 【追記】コマンドプロンプト、powershellそれぞれで`conda -vasion`でconda環境ではないことを確認(確認の方法はあっていますか？)
- 【追記】紹介して頂いた以下のコードの結果

```
import sys
import pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

```
['',
'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
```

プログラミング初学者なので、足りない情報があったら教えてください。

【追記】コマンドプロンプトで`python`としてインタプリタを起動して、`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`とすれば、エラーは出ませんでした。(依然VSCではエラーになります。)

Comment: 3つめの`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`で出来るはずですが。[Beautifulsoupがimportできません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/83342/26370) VSCodeの設定とか仮想環境とかの問題ではありませんか？ [【Python入門】venv仮想環境の使い方を習得してVS Codeでの開発をスムーズに！](https://engineer-lifestyle-blog.com/code/python/vscode-venv-for-beginner/) VSCode上ではなく、コマンドプロンプトのコンソールウインドウ上で`py`とやってインタプリタを起動し、`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`を入力してみてはどうでしょう？ それで問題無いならVSCodeの設定や仮想環境の問題でしょう。

Comment: @kunif さん、conda 環境と書いてあるので venv を紹介するのは誤解のもとと思います。

Comment: 済みませんね。見落としていました。ではこの辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Anaconda＋VScodeの環境の作る方法を解説](https://python0to1.com/499/), [WindowsでPython、Anaconda、VSCodeのインストールとPython開発環境を構築する方法](https://www.nblog09.com/w/2020/11/22/windows-python/), [【最新】VSCodeでAnaconda3(Python)を実行する方法(Windows)](https://tech-diary.net/vscode-anaconda3-python/), [Pythonの開発環境をANACONDAとVisual Studio Codeを利用してwindows10で作成](https://whitemarkn.com/learning-ai/visual-studio-code/) そしてパッケージは全て`conda`でインストールすることですね。

Comment: 大文字にするのは 'B'と 'S'で合ってます。conda環境は OSから見てアプリのインストール情報なので (condaコマンドではなく)別の何か。Windowsについては分かりません。VS Codeでのみエラーなら, 右下 言語モードの隣辺りに現在使用している Python環境出てるはずで, たぶん違うものを指し示してるのでは？

Comment: Pythonインタプリンタで問題無いならVSCodeの設定でしょうね。この辺の記事を参考に設定変更してみてください。[Work with Python interpreters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters), [初期設定 - PythonをVS Codeで...](https://endy-tech.hatenablog.jp/entry/get_started_with_python_with_vscode#%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A), [インタプリタの切り替え - VS Code で...](https://blog.logical.co.jp/entry/2021/04/19/160000#%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AE%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E6%9B%BF%E3%81%88), [Python のインタプリタを設定する](https://python.softmoco.com/devenv/how-to-setup-vs-code-for-python.php#3)

Comment: 解決しました！ご協力ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Work with Python interpreters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters)を参考に、VSCodeで指定するインタプリタを選択しなおして解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

[Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) はパッケージ管理システムです

> Conda is an open source package management system

新たにパッケージインストールするとき依存関係チェックしたり, 場合によっては微妙にバージョン上げ下げして調整したり …
なので, condaの預かり知らぬうちに (pip など使用し)あるパッケージをすげ替えるとか … たぶん危険です

---

conda環境を利用するのなら, まず確認して

```bash
$ conda list beautiful
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1           py39h06a4308_0
```

存在しなければ **condaでインストール**, 旧いようなら update (もしくはチャンネル考慮)

あるいは, **conda環境から抜けて pip**使うのがよいかも

---

##### 【追記】

質問から conda環境の条件消えたけど, 本当に conda入ってなかったのか十分確認したほうがよいでしょう

[Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) の base環境には BeautifulSoup が含まれていて, 仮にその辺り破壊したのなら (質問のように) `ModuleNotFoundError` が出たりするようなので。
(その場合, Anaconda 含め 全ての Python環境(一旦)アンインストールしたほうがよく, そのままだと「砂上の楼閣」築くようなものなので)

環境が破壊されていないのなら

- `import` に失敗している行を示すことは大事です (大文字小文字の間違いがあるかもしれない)
- 以下のスクリプト試してみると, もしかしたらある程度状況分かるかも (質問に追記してみてください)

  ```py
  import sys
  import pprint

  pprint.pprint(sys.path)
  ```

Comment: 申し訳ありません、Pythonの環境について理解が甘かったようです。
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3104/
からダウンロードしてきたPythonを使っています。

Comment: condaには Python自体も入ってて, バージョン管理の対象です。conda環境使うなら condaで Pythonバージョン指定しないとトラブルの元 (必要であれば手順記します)。conda使わないのなら別のところからダウンロードしてても問題ないでしょう。

Comment: 3.10.4 は チャンネル`pkgs/main` にも存在するようなので, [こちらの手順で condaでインストール可能](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88948/anacondaでpythonのバージョンを変更する/88950#88950)です

Comment: 少し調べて来ました。おそらくconda環境ではないので、質問を編集させて頂きます。(今のところconda環境を使う予定はありません。)
現在、
python.org/downloads/release/python-3104 からダウンロードしてきたPythonを、VSCの marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python の拡張機能を使って実行している、といった状態です。
各モジュールはpipでインストールしています